# How to sign up with facebook plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have my own registration written with php and I also want users to sign up with facebook plugin.  I checked the manual but I cant see a plugin like sign up there are sites that implement this plugin there is only login plugin.

How can i do this with login plugin?
Im new to web programming is it so hard to implement facebook plugin for a newbie?

Comment: No its not hard.Start writing code and ask for help when you are stuck.

Comment: read this first if somehow you missed it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/